# How to run command block in Vagrant once

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

How to run command block in Vagrantfile only once. Try to use **if** case, but without success.

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

$hosts = {
    "node-1" => { memory: 1024, cpus: 2 },
    "node-2" => { memory: 4096, cpus: 2 }
}

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|      
  $hosts.each_with_index do |(hostname, parameters), index|  
    config.vm.define vm_name = hostname do |vm_config|
      vm_config.vm.hostname = hostname

      config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo index=#{index}"

      if index == 0
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./bootstrap-scripts/node-1.sh"
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Console result:

```
==> node-1: Importing base box 'generic/ubuntu1804'...
...
==> node-1: Running provisioner: shell...
    node-1: Running: inline script
    node-1: index=0

==> node-2: Importing base box 'generic/ubuntu1804'...
...
==> node-2: Running provisioner: shell...
    node-2: Running: inline script
    node-2: index=0
==> node-2: Running provisioner: shell...
    node-2: Running: inline script
    node-2: index=1
```

The goal is to run "./bootstrap-scripts/control.sh" script for the first machine only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [vagrant documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/tips.html#loop-over-vm-definitions):

> The inner portion of multi-machine definitions and provider overrides are lazy-loaded. This can cause issues if you change the value of a variable used within the configs
>   ...

The inner behaviour of `each_with_index` probably trigger the documented gotcha, that's why your node-2 loop through both indexes. So try using the node name in your if instead.

Also you need to use `vm_config` not `config` is you want provisioner to apply for each node.

Comment: Using `vm_config` instead of `config` - helps, thanks!

Comment: No problem, I glad you were able to fix it. Just by curiosity did you try to use the node name instead of the index in the if ? Did that made any change ? Like did you need both modifcation to make it work ?